How can I load data using Dask and process it with deep learning algorithms (TensorFlow)?
I want to process a large dataset with deep learning algorithms, which were implemented in the TensorFlow framework. I used Dask for loading the data, but the model's accuracy reached 100% in the second epoch. In the same manner, I used Numpy for data loading in the system with higher RAM, and the results didn't achieve 100% even after 50 epochs.
How can I fix the problem in Dask?

Hi, the question here is unclear. How did you use Dask to feed TensorFlow model training? How do you explain the accuracy difference? What really is your problem?
